# Previous marking nullified while using ifelse condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

Here is my data -

```
library(data.table)
    basefile2 = data.table(States = c("California","California", "California", "Texas","Texas","Texas", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio"),
                          Cities = c("LA", "California City", "San Fran", "Houston", "Dallas", "Austin", "Columbus", "Cleaveland", "Wooster"))
```

And here is my code -

```
Market = function(state, city){

  if (missing(state))  stop("Enter State",
                               call. = FALSE)


  if (missing(city))  stop("Enter City(ies)",
                            call. = FALSE)


  basefile2 <<- basefile2[, "Consideration" := ifelse(States == state & Cities %in% city, "Y", 
                                                    ifelse("Consideration" %in% colnames(basefile) & "Consideration" == "Y", "Y", "N"))]


}


Market(state = "California",
       city = c("LA", "California City"))

Market(state = "Texas",
       city = c("Dallas", "Austin"))
```

The previous marking in the consideration column when state was California is getting nullified. Yes, I need to input different states in separate functions to due to certain input constraints

Here is my output

```
       States          Cities Consideration
1: California              LA             N
2: California California City             N
3: California        San Fran             N
4:      Texas         Houston             N
5:      Texas          Dallas             Y
6:      Texas          Austin             Y
7:       Ohio        Columbus             N
8:       Ohio      Cleaveland             N
9:       Ohio         Wooster             N
```

Where as, the output I need is the consideration column must have "Y" in the California City, LA, Austin & Dallas.

Comment: @akrun since I want basefile2 to be a global data table & access it outside a function too, hence I assigned <<- and not := ... Fixed the typos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add the "Consideration" column to the data.table at the start, and then use that as a condition to update within the function so that previous updates are not replaced.

```
library(data.table)
basefile2 <- data.table(...) # as you had

basefile2[, Consideration := "N"] # initialize the column
```

---

```
Market <- function(state, city){

 basefile2 <<- basefile2[Consideration=="N",    # Only update if this is "N"
                 "Consideration" := ifelse(States == state & Cities %in% city, "Y", "N")]
}
```

---

Or maybe like this:

---

```
Market <- function(state, city){

    basefile2 <<- basefile2[States == state & Cities %in% city, Consideration := "Y"]
}
```

---

```
Market(state = "California", city = c("LA", "California City"))
Market(state = "Texas", city = c("Dallas", "Austin"))

basefile2
       States          Cities Consideration
1: California              LA             Y
2: California California City             Y
3: California        San Fran             N
4:      Texas         Houston             N
5:      Texas          Dallas             Y
6:      Texas          Austin             Y
7:       Ohio        Columbus             N
8:       Ohio      Cleaveland             N
9:       Ohio         Wooster             N
```